# Redirect all pages ( from a server to another's homepage) except one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

1. I need to redirect all pages of a website (`domain example: www.example.com`) to another's homepage (`www.new.example`) but I don't want to redirect the `www.example.com/administrator` page.

   How can I do that and where should I place the code: In `.htaccess` or in *Cpanel -> Redirects*?
2. In case the 301 redirect is not good, if I delete it or (remove the code in `.htaccess` and save) my old site would still be online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect all URLs, except `/administrator` to `www.new.example` then use something like the following using mod_rewrite at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^administrator$ https://www.new.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

(What about static resources that might be used by `/administrator`?)

> or in Cpanel ->Redirects?

cPanel simply edits `.htaccess` for you, but it is very limited and prone to error. (It would likely place these directives in the wrong place, as it always places redirects at the end of the file - which is nearly always the wrong place for redirects!)

> 2. In case the 301 redirect is not good, if I delete it or (remove the code in htaccess and save) my old site would still be online?

Always test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached persistently by browsers so they are not necessarily "quick" to reverse.